# Is it possible to update micropython via wifi?

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I wanted to update the application of an ESP8266 that I have very little physical access to. The new application uses the function `uasyncio.create_task(coro)` which is not available in Micropython 1.12. Fortunately I was able to replace the function with `uasyncio.ensure_future(obj)`.

Nevertheless, I have the question of whether the area in the flash with Micropython can be updated via WLAN at the runtime of the "OS" Micropython?

Does Micropython run completely in RAM?

A Linux kernel, for example, can easily be exchanged at runtime so that the new kernel is loaded at the next boot.

Comment: Well, unless your WiFi is entirely hardware driven how are you going to run the wifi part of the firmware while you also overwrite it with new firmware? You're basically asking if you can change your shoes while you a running, without missing a step. The answer is probably "no".

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69781423/edit) your question and improve it. Please add more information as to why you are trying this. Please add also what you tried until now. Read this for hints how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Over The Air (OTA) updates are possible. Your device has to be configured for OTA updates before hand with two OTA partitions. MicroPython will run from one of the OTA partitions. You can use MicroPython to retrieve and write new firmware to the other OTA partition. When you perform a reset the processor will start the application in the other OTA partition. You can do this over and over again ping-ponging between the two OTA partitions.

[See these links for some examples](https://awesome-micropython.com/#ota)

Comment: Unfortunately, the links only point to ways to update the application, but not micropython.

Comment: As far as the ESP is concerned MicroPython is the application.

Comment: i would call it os. It doesn't matter, it can't be updated with the specified modules...